# add query parameters to an existing url string

Tags: url

In Magento if I have a URL string, is there any built in function that I can use to add query parameters to it?

In the exact case I am looking at I am generating a category URL and then I want to add a set of query parameters on top of it.

I am doing the following:

```
$categoryUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(1)->getUrl();
```

I want to then add the following query parameters:

```
array('param1' => 'myparam1','param2' => 'myparam2');
```

I then want to end up with:

```
http://mysite.com/mycategory.html?param1=myparam1&param2=myparam2
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to obtain? How are you generating the category url and what is the desired result?

Comment: Updated question to reflect this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is a 'built in' way to achieve this.
The method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url::getUrl()` does not accept any parameters.
You can override the method, but unless you need something like this for all categories I don't see a point on doing it.
I think the cheapest way is to add the parameters directly.

```
$params = array('param1' => 'myparam1','param2' => 'myparam2');
$categoryUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(1)->getUrl();
$urlParams = array();
foreach ($params as $name=>$value){
    $urlParams[] = $name.'='.urlencode($value);
}
$urlParams = implode('&', $urlParams);
if ($urlParams){
    $glue = '?';
    if (strpos($categoryUrl, $glue) !== false){//this should never happen - but just in case
        $glue = '&';
    }
    $categoryUrl .= $glue.$urlParams;
}
```

You can make this a method in a helper to avoid writing the code each time you need it.

For any other url that you construct through `Mage::getUrl()` you can pass query params like this:

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action', array('param1'=>'val1', '_query'=>array('p1'=>'v1', 'p2'=>'v2')));
```

the code above will generate the following:

> http://mysite.com/module/controller/action/param1/val1/?p1=v1&p2=v2

Comment: @Simon...when downvoting, give a reason.

Comment: sorry, was a bit too fast - did not like the first code block, because there is a built-in way to achieve this, but you also show that way, so all good.

Comment: ... and now I cannot change my vote any more (which I dislike a lot at all SE sites). Anyway, I think it is quite strange that you can see who downvoted your answer :/

Comment: @Simon. I think I was a bit wrong on this one. See what benmarks wrote in an other answer. So your down vote had a good reason. I just stated that you should give a reason when downvoting. And rest assured, you cannot see who downvoted answers on SO. I just investigated a bit. Because this website does not have a huge amount of votes and users it's kind of easy to find out who downvoted. I will not tell you how I found out, but all I can say is that it's kind of easy to see who downvoted on Sundays and Mondays. :).

Comment: LOL okay :) Yeah, I think Bens answer should have been the accepted one on this question. Anyway, thanks and keep up the good work!

Comment: how to get that parameter in phtml file ..

Answer (score 27):

```
echo Mage::getUrl('',
    array(
        '_direct' => Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->loadByIdPath('category/1')->getRequestPath(),
        '_query' => array('param1' => 'myparam1','param2' => 'myparam2')
    )
);
```

Comment: This is the real answer.

Comment: I don't think that there is a best answer to this, as passing params in a URL is not specific to Magento, although Magento contains a method for it.

Comment: @TylerMaginnis *"is there any built in function [in Magento] that I can use to add query parameters [to a URL string]?"*

Answer (score 8):

You can use *core/url* helper:

```
$params = array('param1' => 'myparam1', 'param2' => 'myparam2');
$newCategoryUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->addRequestParam($categoryUrl, $params);
```