# How to get or append some extra query param to url

Tags: magento2.2, url, toplinks, parameter

I have added some links in top. i want get query param from url and append in to every links in top dynamically

like my links are =  `test1`,  `test2`, `test3`

My mail url is = `https://apcd.com`

When some one use = `https://abcd.com?id=123`

When any one click on any link in top normally it will open like =  `https://abcd.com/test1` but i need `https://abcd.com/test1?id=123`

I am able to add like this but user changed `https://abcd.com?id=1234` immediately not effecting in to that links when i flush cache that time only it effecting any idea to resolve this issue

I have create one phmtl file

```
 <?php  $blockObject= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Pawan\Customerids\Block\Index');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$id = $blockObject->getRequest()->getParam('id');

$storeurl=$storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
$storeurl = rtrim($storeurl, '/');
?>
<li class="nav item ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
    <a href="<?php echo $storeurl.'/home'.$id; ?>" id="ui-id-3" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav item ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
    <a href="<?php echo $storeurl.'/our-experts'.$id; ?>" id="ui-id-4" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">OUR EXPERTS</a>
</li>
<li class="nav item ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
    <a href="<?php echo $storeurl.'/about-us'.$id; ?>" id="ui-id-5" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">ABOUT US</a>
</li>
<li class="nav item ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
    <a href="<?php echo $storeurl.'/contact'.$id; ?>" id="ui-id-6" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">SUPPORT</a>
</li>
<li class="nav item ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
    <a href="<?php echo $storeurl.'/faq-s'.$id; ?>" id="ui-id-7" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">FAQS</a>
</li>
```

I called this file default_head_blocks.xml it i showing fine

Comment: Can you please update your question with what you did so far.

Comment: @Ramkishan updated pls check once

Comment: I can see that they are cms pages links, when you append $id then it'll become home1234, contatc1234 etc.
Can you please explain bit more what is exactly you want to do from this.

Comment: i will apped ? in between.like home?1234. when you link http://abcd.com?id=1234.after some i will change http://abcd.com?id=1235 but not effecting in all links when i flush cache and refresh it will effect

Comment: @Ramkishan samelike need to manupulate every url like below
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5000/add-query-parameters-to-an-existing-url-string